# VHDL: Instantiated component generic array index out of range

Tags: vhdl, fpga, vivado

I'm trying to implement an encryption algorithm in VHDL, and I have created a Feedback Shift Register component with generic parameters to improve reusability. It's my first time using generics and arrays, so please bear with me.

This component takes the feedback bits as an input, and it connects some of its bits (taps) to an output port, but this connections can be changed using a generic parameter. Code for the FSR component:

```
library ieee;
  use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
  use ieee.numeric_std.all;
  use work.fsr_taps_type.all;
  entity FSR is

    generic (
    r_WIDTH  : integer; -- Register width
    r_STEP   : integer;  -- Update step
    r_FWIDTH  : integer; -- Feedback output width
    r_HWIDTH  : integer; -- h-function output width
    r_TAPS    : TAPS;           -- Change the size according to the number of taps
    r_STATE   : TAPS
    );

    port (
    clk      : in std_logic;
    rst      : in std_logic;
    fb_in    : in std_logic_vector ((r_STEP-1) downto 0);
    init     : in std_logic;
    ini_data : in std_logic_vector ((r_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
    out_data : out std_logic_vector ((r_STEP-1) downto 0);
    fb_out   : out std_logic_vector ((r_FWIDTH-1) downto 0);
    h_out    : out std_logic_vector ((r_HWIDTH-1) downto 0)
    );
  end entity;

architecture behavioural of FSR is
signal shifted,shifted_next  : std_logic_vector((r_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
begin
process(clk,rst)
begin
if rst = '1' then
  shifted <= (others => '0');
elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
  shifted <= shifted_next;
end if;
end process;

process (fb_in,init,ini_data,shifted)
begin
  if init = '1' then
    shifted_next <= ini_data;
  else
    shifted_next <= shifted((r_WIDTH-r_STEP-1) downto 0) & fb_in;
  end if;
end process;
out_data <= shifted ((r_WIDTH-1) downto (r_WIDTH-r_STEP));

-- The bits defined in the r_TAPS and r_STATE arrays are connected to the outputs in the same order as they are written (left to right)
-- Example: r_TAPS := (10,6) will create fb_out (1 downto 0) = bit10 & bit 6, in that order
-- Connect taps in the order of r_TAPS
    gen_feedback: for I in (r_FWIDTH-1) downto 0 generate
      fb_out(I) <= shifted(r_STATE(r_FWIDTH-I-1));
    end generate gen_feedback;

-- Connect output bits for h function
    gen_h: for I in (r_HWIDTH-1) downto 0 generate
      h_out(I) <= shifted(r_STATE(r_HWIDTH-I-1));
    end generate gen_h;

end architecture;
```

My problem comes when instantiating this component twice in the same file, using different generic values. This is the generic map of both instances:

```
LFSR : FSR
generic map (
  r_WIDTH  => 128,
  r_STEP   => STEP,
  r_FWIDTH => 6,
  r_HWIDTH => 7,
  r_TAPS  (0 to 5) => (128,121,90,58,47,32),
  r_STATE (0 to 6)  => (34,49,68,86,108,115,120)
)

NFSR : FSR
generic map (
  r_WIDTH  => 128,
  r_STEP   => STEP,
  r_FWIDTH => 29,
  r_HWIDTH => 2,
  r_TAPS  (0 to 28) => (40,36,35,33,106,104,103,58,50,46,117,115,111,110,88,80,101,69,67,63,125,61,60,44,128,102,72,37,32),
  r_STATE  => (33,116)
)
```

When I only create the first instance, the elaboration works as expected and Vivado gives no error whatsoever. However, when I add the second instance, I get an out of range error:

```
ERROR: [Synth 8-97] array index 0 out of range (FSR.vhdl:54)
```

Line 54 is the line inside the first for generate loop:

```
fb_out(I) <= shifted(r_STATE(r_FWIDTH-I-1));
```

Only the second instance gives an error. I have tried copying the parameters from the first instance into the second, and I still get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I added the whole code for the FSR component.

EDIT 2: I changed the type declaration for TAPS, so that the array is constrained:

```
type TAPS is array (0 to 31) of integer;
```

This seems to be working, I just have to add an others statement to fill the unused array numbers, so this:

```
r_TAPS  (0 to 5) => (128,121,90,58,47,32)
```

Becomes this:

```
r_TAPS  (0 to 5) => (128,121,90,58,47,32,others =>0)
```

As I said before, I'm new to arrays in VHDL, so I would like to know if there is a way to do this for arbitrarily long arrays using an unconstrained array type.

Comment: This is not an MCVE. How are we supposed to identify line 54? Also, what do you think the index range of each of those array aggregates is? Hint : the lowest Integer is not zero... Also, I would recommend using suitable ranged subtypes of Natural, rather than Integer.

Comment: As @Brian Drummond alerady said, it's hard to guess without the full file. But I would guess it is this line:

`fb_out(I) <= shifted(r_STATE(r_FWIDTH-I-1));`
At some point `r_FWIDTH-I-1` is -1.

Comment: My guess is the array aggregate with no explicit range constraint - it'll start at -2**31, so 0 will definitely be out of range.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'm still learning and this is the first time I use arrays in VHDL. Am I not constraining the array when I instantiate the component? As in `r_TAPS (0 to 28)`? Would it be better to constrain the array size in the type declaration, given that the values will never be higher than a certain number? I could change the maximum size when/if I needed a bigger array, but I feel like there should be a better solution... 

I'll upload the full code ASAP.

Comment: Brian and Staszek are close. For `fb_out(I) <= shifted(r_STATE(r_FWIDTH - I - 1));` and `NFSR` with values  r_FWIDTH = 29  and `r_STATE  => (33,116)`, 29 is out of the index range of r_STATE. Provide an [MCVe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), In a simulator this would be a bounds run-time error. There's a hint, simulate first.  Your generic constants aren't compatible here. Use a natural range for your unbound array definition as Brian recommends. You should simulate before synthesis.

Comment: Yes, `r_Taps` is constrained. Now look at `r_STATE  => (33,116)`.